# How do I setup where my data goes for my form? HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, location

I made a form for my website, I just don't know how to setup where the information they fill out goes to. I've searched around forums for info, and from what I can tell I need to create a PHP page somewhere. Can anyone give me any tips on how I would start?

Here is my code for the submit button on the code

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="Form/New Text Document.txt"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You data will goto  html_form_action.asp , collect the data there using some variable for further use . To use PHP , change action to "Some_PHP_PAGE_NAME.php"

```
<form action="Some_PHP_PAGE_NAME.php" method="get">
NAME :<input type="text" name="fname">
```

PHP code

```
 <?php 
    $name =$_GET_['fname'];
echo $fname;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

see the following example

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When the user fills out the form above and clicks the submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file named "welcome.php". The form data is sent with the HTTP POST method. To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables. The "welcome.php" looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. In your case, form data send into `action="html_form_action.asp"`

**On submit, send the form-data to a file named "html_form_action.asp" (to process the input).**

Even you can send the value on the same page even.

```
 <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
     Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The formaction attribute overrides the action attribute of the `<form>` element.**

So remove formaction="Form/New Text Document.txt"  from submit